# Method return type using enclosed Generic class?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to write a generic request generator method which will return different objects like below:

```
GenricClass<Object1> genCls1 = getNewRequest(Object1.class);
GenricClass<Object2> genCls2 = getNewRequest(Object2.class);
GenricClass<Object3> genCls3 = getNewRequest(Object3.class);
```

I want this `getNewRequest` to return an object which has enclosing generic class object.

How should the signature of my `getNewRequest` method ?

```
public `?` getNewRequest(Class classtype) {...}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either declare a generic type parameter in the class that contains the method `getNewRequest`, or directly in the method.

For example, declare generic parameter `T` in the method `getNewRequest`:

```
public <T> GenricClass<T> getNewRequest(Class<T> classtype)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the classType instance of T as an argument and returning a GenericClass of the same class type. Somewhat like :

```
public GenericClass<T> getNewRequest(T classtype) { 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like that:

```
public <T> GenericClass<T> getNewRequest(Class<T> classtype) {

}
```